Why doesn't optional chaining placate TypeScript?
Let's say I have the following event handler (in React):
onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
     const link = e.target.href;

I understand why TypeScript complains about the above code: e.target could be an <a> tag (in which case it will have an href), or it could be some other element that doesn't have an href, and things could break if it doesn't.
But when I use the optional chaining operator, it shouldn't matter whether e.target has an href or not:
onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
     const link = e.target?.href;

And the same is true of this (more verbose) version:
onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
     if (!e.target.href) return;
     const link = e.target.href;

But no matter what, TypeScript gives me Property 'href' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339) error.
How can I express "I don't care whether e.target has an href or not" (without using @ts-ignore)?

• Does this question depend on React? If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] your code so that it's a [mre] that doesn't need external libraries to demonstrate the issue. • I'm confused why changing e.target.href to e.target?.href would have anything to do with the presence or absence of href. The optional chaining only changes what happens if e.target were itself undefined. If e.target is always non-nullish, then e.target?.href doesn't change anything. Is optional chaining a red herring in this question?

It does not require React, but context is important (you can't have a MouseEvent without some sort of DOM library like React) so I included React code.  And the optional chaining isn't a red herring, it's the entire point of the question!

The question is, when Typescript knows you have an object (eg. a MouseEvent object) and you know that object might have a property (or might not), like href, how do you tell Typescript "it might have this href property (the one I'm optionally chaining)" so it doesn't cause an error.

The optional chaining deals with e.target itself being null or undefined, not whether or not it has an href property if it isn't, so yes it's a red herring. You have various options, e.g. use a more specific event type to start with or narrow the value you receive to one.

@Jared Smith Yes; I will flag.

TL;DR the compiler doesn't allow you to check a type at runtime that way because you are making the dangerous assumption that because a property is present and non-nullish that it is what you think it is...

(Also just don't put click event handlers on anchor elements, use an actual button.)

In this specific case that's not an option (using delegated events to handle events originating in a div full of rendered markdown)

Typescript complains because the HTMLElement interface doesn't have the href attribute. This is because this interface represents all the possible DOM elements, so it has their common properties.
You should use HTMLAnchorElement instead.
If you cant define e: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, you can cast later in the function using const target = e.target as HTMLAnchorElement.
Note that this approach is safe only if you are sure that e.target is an HTMLAnchorElement.
If you are treating generic HTMLElements, you can use a type guard:
const target = e.target
if ("href" in target) {
  // here you can use `target.href`
}

Or, if you want a dedicated function
const isAnchorElem = (target): target is HTMLAnchorElement => "href" in target
const target = e.target
if (isAnchorElem(target)) {
  // here `target` will be of type `HTMLAnchorElement`
}



That makes sense, but it won't always be an anchor element: the event is just set to trigger on whatever element gets clicked, and while that element may be an anchor ... it may not :(. So saying that the event will always be one seems wrong.

Okay, then it seems the case to use a type guard

Yes, specifically (it seems) it has to be an in-based type guard, for this sort of thing.  So frustrating that you need to add entire extra if statements to otherwise valid/working code just to tell TS stuff it should be able to figure out.

The problem is that your typescript code has been compiled into javascript code at runtime, so it has no access to information such as "what properties there are in my object". It can only statically infer types, so "extra if" are necessary to make the code type safe

But sometimes a variable may or may not have a property ... and that's ok, right?  I wish Typescript had a way of saying "give me foo.bar, and if foo doesn't have a bar, that's ok (I'll use the undefined)".  Instead you're forced to add otherwise pointless if statements to "narrow" things.

Yeah, in that scenario doing foo?.bar is okay, but here you are dealing with a type that never has the property you want, that's why the type guard is needed. In the function signature you are telling the compiler "my target has this interface", and in the body function you are trying to access properties outside of the interface you told the compiler. The error you were facing just stated that.

Thank you, that really clarified things.
